# How to know to which table column belongs to, in a join query in oracle

Tags: java, eclipse, oracle11g

I have a query (complex queries with joins and sub queries). I want to extract table names, aliases and column names. I was able to do this using eclipse data tools in java. I want to know which column belongs to which table. I explored a lot but unable to find any solution.

```
Select or.name from nametable or inner join place p on or.id=p.id.
```

Any help is greatly appreciated

Comment: You usally use JPA with Hibernate or Eclipselink to abstract your database in Java. There you define all contrains like foreign keys. Otherwise, you may specify your question a bit better.

Comment: Yes you are right but we use jdbc so apart from eclipse data tools im not able to find any solution

Comment: Are you looking for a tool like ANTLR with a SQL grammar?

Comment: I thought of ANTLR option but it will take time in learning and implementing it. So in the short span only option which I can see is eclipse data tools